# Python Error importing package in windows

Tags: python, importerror

First off sorry about my English. Here's my question:

I'm really new to programming and I really want to learn Python. That's why I've been reading this book: HeadFirst Python and also joined this website.
Everything was great until I've stumbled into this error I keep getting everytime I import the nester package that I've created.
Why is that happening?

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import nester
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\nester.py", line 1
    Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:16:59) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any answers from you guys will be of great help.

Comment: What version of python are you using? Seems like you are importing a package for a different python version (3.5.0) and you are using another version.

Comment: i'm using a python 3.5.0, cube was right i somewhat included the text on top of IDLE, i think i should use another text editor, I keep messing with simple things like this when using IDLE, but thank you for the response man

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that `nester.py` starts with a line saying `Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:16:59) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`. It looks like you managed to put output of the interpreter into the file instead of your source code :-)

Comment: if you're doing `import nester`, then you need to call the method `nester.print_lol(something)`. There are other options, see here: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Comment: Thank you man, that did the trick, I appreciate it so much., really helpful